# check if string of parenthesis is balanced by doing certain operation on string

Tags: string, algorithm, data-structures, segment-tree, range-query

Given string of parenthesis we have to do 2 kinds of operation:

1. flip- changes the i-th parenthesis into the opposite one(left->right , right->left)
2. check- if the string is a balanced parenthesis expression

length of the string is at max 30000.

No of operation to be performed is at max
100000.

what kind of data structure should one use to solve this kind of problem?

Is Segment Tree a suitable data structure?

If yes how should one use it?

Example

string = ()((

no of operation=4

1. flip 4 {new string is ()()}
2. check {string is balanced}
3. flip 2{new string becomes ((()}
4. check{string is not balanced}

Comment: Probably misinterpreting the question, but are you looking for an algorithm that given an unbalanced string, turns it into a balanced string with the lowest possible amount of flips? Or are you only looking for a way to check if a string is balanced?

Comment: @user2464424 the string given might be balanced/unbalanced The algorithm I was looking forward is given two operation flip and check there can be any number of flips or check(at most 100000) for each check I have to determine whether entire string is balanced and for each flip i i have to flip the ith character

Comment: Why are you starting with a flip before even checking the string? And why do you continue after check passes? And how do you know which character to flip? Does check return true/false or the position of the first problem?

Comment: Still not clear, are you (1) looking for an implementation for the functions `flip` and `check`, or (2) for an algorithms that, given those two functions, can "fix" an unbalanced string of parentheses, or (3) both?

Answer (score 1):

Let every `(` be a `+1` and every `)` be a `-1`. Then a string of parenthesis is balanced iff sum for entire string is zero and sum for every range `[0, k]` is non-negative.

Let us define two functions for substring `[i,j]`, `sum` and `min`. `sum` is obvious, and `min(i,j)` defined as minimum from all `sum(i,k)` where `k <= j`.

So

```
sum(i,k) = sum(i,j) + sum(j+1, k)
```

And

```
min(i,k) = MIN( min(i,j), sum(i,j) + min(j + 1, k) )
```

Now we can build a binary tree, where leafs are `+1`'s and `-1`'s, and root is an entire range `[0, N-1]`. For every node we keep `min` and `sum`.

Query for balance is obvious: we check for `root.min >= 0` and `root.sum == 0`, so `O(1)`.

Flip is done by updating leaf node and propagating changes to the root. No more than `log(N)+1` nodes are updated, and every update is `O(1)`, so `O(logN)`.

Answer (score 0):

A function that checks whether a string is balanced is easily made. Stepping through the string, increment a zero-initialized value if a "(" character is met and decrement it if ")" is met. If the result is 0 and it never went below 0 during the run, the string is balanced.
Flipping the parenthesis at nth position of the string is trivial.

Here's a simple implementation in javascript that flips a random character of the string in a loop and checks the validity of the resulting string after each flip.

http://jsbin.com/vagalijoca/edit?html,console

```
function checkbalanceness(str){
  var res = 0;
  for(i=0;i<str.length;i++) {
    str[i]=="(" ? res++ : res--;
    if (res < 0) break;
  }
  return res == 0;
}

function flipp(str, i){
  if (i >= str.length) return str;
  return str[i]=="(" ?
    str.substr(0,i) + ")" + str.substr(i+1) :
    str.substr(0,i) + "(" + str.substr(i+1) ;
}

//initial string
var curr = "()(())";
//operations to be executed
var ops = 40;

console.log('initial string: ' + curr + ' ' + checkbalanceness(curr));
console.log('operations: ' + ops);
console.log('start');
var ii;
var chartoflip;
for(ii=0;ii<ops;ii+=2){
  chartoflip = (ii/2)%(curr.length);
  curr = flipp(curr, chartoflip);
  console.log((ii) + ' - flip char ' + chartoflip + ': ' + curr);
  console.log((ii+1) + ' - checking ' + curr + ' ' + checkbalanceness(curr));
}
console.log('end');
```